# Testing whether a large list of alpha characters is contained in a string (without using RegEx)

Tags: python

**Without using RegEx**, I'd like to be able to test whether a given string contains certain lowercase characters (e.g. 22 of the 26 lower-case characters in the alphabet).

For example:

```
my_str = 'foobar'
if 'c' in str or 'd' in my_str or 'e' in my_str:   # I don't want to enumerate the entire alphabet
    print('fails the test')
else:
    print('passes the test')
```

This approach works, but I would have to enumerate most of the lowercase alphabet.  This is a hacky approach!

Is there another way to do this?  (yes, I know that RegEx would be a good choice, but not for my use case)

Thanks!

Comment: `all(c not in {"c", "d", "e"} for c in str)`?

Comment: Don't use `str` as a variable. Ever. Never use a builtin as a variable.

Comment: @Codeman -- yes, my bad!  Fixed it.

Comment: Couldn't you use a for loop (through the alpha chars) and then use `if ... in`? (Dawg's approach is probably better though)

Comment: How do you imagine specifying those characters if not by enumerating them? Can you express them with some kind of rule?

Comment: *"RegEx would be a good choice, but not for my use case"* - Why not?

Comment: This is a toy example.  The maintainability of RegEx could be an issue for us.

Comment: Why would a regex be harder to maintain than something else?

Comment: Personal preference.  It's like asking why a gasoline engine would be easier to maintain than a diesel engine.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a set and perform a set `&`:

```
>>> set('foobar') & set('cde')
set()
```

An empty set is equivalent to all your `or`'s

And it will work with 22 characters.

So your `if` could be written as:

```
t = ('foobar','coobar')
for s in t:
    if set(s) & set('cde'):
        print(f'"{s}" fails the test')
    else:
        print(f'"{s}" passes the test')
```

Prints:

```
"foobar" passes the test
"coobar" fails the test
```

Comment: This way you also "enumerate most of the lowercase alphabet", though.

Comment: Python speed vs C speed... sets are written in C and enumerate is in Python.

Comment: Speed isn't what they complained about there.

Comment: They said enumerate, not `enumerate`.

Comment: Hmm... I wonder how long the string needs to be for their way to be faster. Not sure I ever measured that, might've just always measured with a million chars or so.

Comment: Interesting... Even for very short strings, their way is twice as fast as yours in my test, and already at length 600, their way is already [ten times faster](https://tio.run/##TdDLDoIwEAXQfb9iwsKCYYExMcaELzFu1CIV@qAdfP08FnFxZzE5ncx0cf2bW2e3ex@mqQnOEGujNJM23gX@v4SIVFM2N/mRtKZdVWVCqHlwFJQqkxdJ2lIkF0hewQrcgG/gFqzBd3AH7sEGbMEO7MEDOIAjmMEj@AF@gl@Ls3LJIirOY0ErmiEvV9XcWn3vemOdH0Lk8fF8ySJtn4Ro0r2ar1OYa9oefj9wynVJPlclxZLsaM4q1JsqVfFb8UFbzrmYpi8) than yours.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a set with the isdisjoint method:

```
my_str = 'foobar'
if not set('cde').isdisjoint(my_str): 
    print('fails the test')
else:
    print('passes the test')
```

If you want to exclude most letters, you can setup your set with all letters and remove the ones that are acceptable:

```
import string

excludeSet = set(string.ascii_lowercase)
excludeSet -= set('aeiou')               # e.g. allow vowels

my_str = 'foobar'
if not excludeSet.isdisjoint(my_str): 
    print('fails the test')
else:
    print('passes the test')
```